# Psycopg2 fetch row into a file (Bean or class)

Tags: python, psycopg2

I have worked with Java before and have worked with hibernate. Please excuse if i use any java literal. 
I have a bean class Person which has attributes firstName, lastName. I am trying to read a row from the database using Psycopg2 and convert it into Person Object automatically.

I read online that by default i can only retrieve data as tuple of tuple or as a dictionary, can someone shed some light around if the above is possible. This will save me from writing a lot of code. (Lazy Dev)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

psycopg2 is a DB driver, used for connection pooling, querying, etc.

It by default returns data as tuples, but it has extras that can be configured to return data as dictionaries or as named tuples (documentation for namedtuples [here](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#namedtuple-cursor) )

If you are looking to have your data returned as a specific object, you should consider using a dedicated ORM such as [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/).